# Comparação entre dois objetos

Tags: javascript

Supondo que eu tenha os seguintes objetos:

```
const dataBody = { name:'luiz', email:'luiz1@gmail.com', cpf:'12345678910' }
const dataDb = { name:'luiz', email:'luiz@gmail.com', cpf:'12345678910' }
```

Como eu faço para comparar cada propriedade dos dois objetos, e criar um novo, com o(s) valor(es) do primeiro, apenas quando a(s) propriedade(s) for(em) diferente(s)?

Este seria o novo objeto:

```
const dataRes = { email: 'luiz1@gmail.com'}
```

pois `dataBody.email != dataDb.email`

Comment: O novo objeto teria apenas uma propriedade? Os demais dados serão perdidos mesmo?

Comment: O novo objeto teria todas as propriedades que fossem diferentes entre os dois objetos comparados.

Comment: Legal, então a resposta do @LLeon já lhe atende! =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
Object.entries(dataBody).forEach(e => {
  if (dataDb[e[0]] !== e[1]) { dataRes[e[0]] = e[1]; }
})
```

```js
const dataBody = { name:'luiz', email:'luiz1@gmail.com', cpf:'12345678910' }
const dataDb = { name:'luiz', email:'luiz@gmail.com', cpf:'12345678910' }
const dataRes = {}

Object.entries(dataBody).forEach(e => {
  if (dataDb[e[0]] !== e[1]) { dataRes[e[0]] = e[1]; }
})

console.log(dataRes);
```